# Coordinate transformation. From differentials to contravariant vectors

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, coordinate-systems, vector-fields, covariance

I have a very silly doubt. If I have two coordinate systems and I want to calculate the coordinate differentials for the second one, I need to use the chain rule for the derivatives so that I obtain

$$d{x^{\prime j}}=\frac{\partial x^{\prime j}}{\partial x^i}d{x^i}$$

Basically, the differentials make an infinitesimal displacement.

However, any resource I read, as a consequence of the above equation, says that it is valid for a contravariant vector, as well.

$${V^{\prime j}}=\frac{\partial x^{\prime j}}{\partial x^i}{V^i}$$

I am missing the reason why we are authorized to write the second equation from the first one. Is there a way to derive it or is it just a definition (of contravariant vector)? In the second case, why is such vector object capable to model the quantities we are interested with?

---

### **A solution (maybe)**

Maybe, I found the solution. Just in case someone needs it, I write it below.
The first equation is about the components of an infinitesimal displacement $d\vec s$.
$$d{\vec s}=d{x^i}\mathbf e_i$$
The above equation is valid for any coordinate system, so that we can write
$$d{\vec s}=d{x^i}\mathbf e_i=d{x^{\prime j}}\mathbf e^\prime_j$$
Now, we can write the $dx^{\prime j}$ as a function of the differentials of the first coordinate system.
$$d{\vec s}=d{x^i}\mathbf e_i  = d{x^{\prime j}}\mathbf e^\prime_j= \frac{\partial x^{\prime j}}{\partial x^i}d{x^i} \mathbf e^\prime_j$$
So, we understand that
$$\mathbf e_i=\frac{\partial x^{\prime j}}{\partial x^i}\mathbf e^\prime_j$$

Now, let $V^i$ be a vector defined from the above basis (we'll find it to be contravariant). We can write
$$\vec V=V^i\mathbf e_i=V^i \frac{\partial x^{\prime j}}{\partial x^i}\mathbf e^\prime_j = V^{\prime j}\mathbf e^\prime_j$$

From the last step, we understand that
$$V^{\prime j}= \frac{\partial x^{\prime j}}{\partial x^i}V^i$$
which is just what we wanted.

Comment: You might want to look at how vectors are defined on a curved manifold, (2) is pretty much just a definition.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is a definition of a covariant vector, one that transforms in the same way as coordinate vectors do. A possible answer on why is this useful is that the construction of covariant and contravariant vectors allows you to build objects that are independent on coordinate transformations.

Answer (score 1):

This question is basic but the Community bot wanted it to be reviewed. Plus
I think OP has an error.

Good on you that you have used the chain rule to derive the (contravariant) transformation law for differentials:
$$\tag{1}
dx^{\,j\,\prime}=\frac{\partial x^\prime_j}{\partial x_i}\,dx^i\,.
$$
It can also be used to derive the (covariant) transformation law for coordinate basis vector fields:
$$\tag{2}
\partial_{x_j}=\frac{\partial x^\prime_i}{\partial x_j}\,\partial_{x_i'}
$$

- These laws should be easy to remember when we "cancel" terms.
- Note that (2) has the prime in the denominator. Your law involving $\mathbf{e}_i$ and $\mathbf{e_i}^\prime$ does not look quite right.
- The *contravariant* transformation law
  $$\tag{3}
  V^{\,j\,\prime}=\frac{\partial x^\prime_j}{\partial x_i}\,V^i\,.
  $$
  for *components* $V^i$ of any vector field follows directly from (2) and is dictated by the principle that we want
  $$\tag{4}
  \boldsymbol{V}=V^i\,\partial_{x_i}=V^{\,i\,\prime}\,\partial_{x^\prime_j}
  $$
  to represent one and the same vector field $\boldsymbol{V}$ in different coordinate systems. To see that just plug in everything and "cancel".

Comment: Is (2) really correct? How can two primed $x$'s be at the denominator in the second member?
Also, why do all your $x$'s, which are coordinates, have the index at the bottom instead of top? I am not a physicist nor a mathematician but I have always seen $x^i$ instead of $x_i$.

Comment: Thanks for spotting. I hope is it is fixed. A common notation for $\partial_{x_i}$ is $\partial_i\,.$ It is also true that $x^i$ is quite common. The point however is where the primes are.