# Landau-Lifshitz vol 2 covariant derivative typo?

Tags: general-relativity

In Vol 2 of L&L §85 (covariant derivative) they want to show that $dA_i$ is not a covariant vector and they write (my translation):

'We derive the transformationformula for the differentials $dA_i$ in curved coordinates. A covariant Vector transforms as

$$ A_i = \frac{\partial x^{\prime k}}{\partial x^i} A^{\prime}_k$$

thus it is:

$$ dA_i=\frac{\partial x^{\prime k}}{\partial x^i} dA^{\prime}_k + A^{\prime}_kd \frac{\partial x^{\prime k}}{\partial x^i} = \frac{\partial x^{\prime k}}{\partial x^i} dA^{\prime}_k + A^{\prime}_k \frac{\partial^2 x^{\prime k}}{\partial x^i\partial x^l} dx^{\prime l}$$.

This is all good and well, but when I try to calculate I get for the last term $$A^{\prime}_k \frac{\partial^2 x^{\prime k}}{\partial x^i\partial x^l} dx^{ l} $$ (no prime at the differential). Is there a typo in LL or is there something I dont understand about coordinate transforms.

Comment: If you suspect a typo, perhaps reference the edition of the book you're using (in case this was corrected in later editions - if it is indeed a typo). The formula is the same in the German edition that I have, which is based on the sixth Russian edition from 1972.

Comment: Seems indeed like a typo to me. If you are interested in a [related](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/563739/coordinate-transformation-from-differentials-to-contravariant-vectors/789743#789743) post which imho has a few hints that help to remember such formulas.